# pytest markers are not working when running doctest with pytest runner

Tags: python, unit-testing, pytest, doctest

Trying to run doctest tests using pytest runner and wanted to use markers functionality to group them and run selectively.

Whole module where doctests are declared is marked as following:

`pytestmark = pytest.mark.mymark`

pytest sort of picks up this marker. I can see that because if I don't declare this marker name in pytest.ini, it gives me a warning.
The problem is that pytest doesn't want to run this test when I'm applying marker filter:

```
> pytest -m mymark
collected 4 items / 4 deselected / 0 selected
```

Any ideas how to make this work?

Answer (score 0):

Creating conftest.py file with the following code fixes the problem:

```
from _pytest.doctest import DoctestItem, DoctestModule


# pylint: disable=unused-argument
def pytest_collection_modifyitems(config, items):
    """pytest hook which gets called after collection is completed"""
    for item in items:
        if(isinstance(item, DoctestItem)
           and isinstance(item.parent, DoctestModule)
           and hasattr(item.parent.module, 'pytestmark')):

            item.own_markers = [item.parent.module.pytestmark.mark]
```

Likely a bug in pytest, so this is a temporary, non-generic solution that just gives you an idea how to address your particular use case.

Answer (score 0):

I would recommend using `pytest.ini` to declare all fixture to avoid warning.

Create a pytest.ini file at `src` level and declare all your markers instead of doctest.

```
[pytest]
addopts = -v --html=report.html --self-contained-html --junitxml="report.xml" --
markers =
    marker_name: description
    sanity: run tests in the directory/module marked as sanity
    regression: run tests in the directory/module marked as regression
```

Comment: Warning is not a problem but an indicator that pytest picks up my doctest marker. Modifying ini file removes warning but does not solve the problem described in this question.

Comment: just to make sure  have you annotated your tests with @pytest.mark.mymark? are you in the folder where this tests are present, or some other dir.

Comment: I've annotated whole module where doctests are defined: "pytestmark = pytest.mark.mymark" does that according to documentation.